# How to add a none option in scikit learn predict

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, leap-motion

I have the next problem, I'm trying to classify one of four hand position, I'm using SVM and this positions will be used to make commands in my program, the predict function works fine, but for example if I made some other gestures (none of the 4 that I use for commands) the predict function try to classify this gesture in one of the original four, I want to know if is possible to say "this gesture is none of the four that I know".

The final function of this is similar to the behaivor of some commands of the kinect in Xbox for example, you can move your hands but the Xbox will only react to a especifict gesture.

I'm using Python, pandas, scikit-learn and leap motion, I training my network with data collected from four gestures.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Carry forward your logic , just as you trained your classifier to identify a gesture , teach it none too , you haven't specified your model pipeline so I can't give a precise method , but for example if u are using images , then add another output classifier that will predict emptiness ie an image with no hand in it or an unrecognised gesture

Comment: I'm using the data collected by the Leap Motion controller, so the prediction is in realtime and I'm always seeing hands, the only diference is that I only want to react to some specific position, so with your logic I need to teach all other possible gestures but I don't want this.

Comment: I don't think you have to teach it all other gestures , it I am understanding your problem correctly , whenever you want to train your none case just do a hand action that isn't one of the four actually want to train it for , randomn hand movement no movement anything basically anything that isn't going to be part of svm decisions boundaries of the 4 desired movements . This is how neural networks are trained for null cases where no object is to be found and they work quite well , I see no reason why this wouldn't work a svm.

Comment: I recommend that you try to train null case for a small dataset vs a single gesture and if you start seeing desirable results then it works if it doesn't then we think of something else . As a side note don't ever be afraid to experiment in this field you never know what may or may not work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of treating this as a classification problem with 4 levels, treat it as a classification problem with 5 levels. 4 levels would correspond to one of the original four and the 5th level can be used for all others.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that its not possible because the fifth level is any other possible position, so is imposible to know how more N "levels" I need to use, I think that I need to uses probabilities to determine if the prediction is correct or not.

Comment: What I meant was, your training set should have data corresponding to 5 levels (1. label each of the actual position as one of the 4 levels. 2. label all others positions as just one single level)

Comment: The english is not my fisrt language so I'm not sure if I don't understand you or if I'm not explaining correctly, but I think that your idea is not suitable for my needs, because I'm using the data that the Leap Motion Controller sends, that is a lot of vectors with 3d coordinates, for the position of the fingers, arm and hand, so my data for training have only the data related to the hands in this four positions and I don't have data for all the other posibles position, that are a lot.

Comment: I actually think this request is legitimate and sad to see it get dismissed out of hand.   For example, it may be very difficult to randomly train gestures that you don't accidentally gesture to be similar to one of the other gestures.   It might actually be legitimatelly useful to conceive of a classifier in which the zero case is not explicitely trained.   I have this situation where its very difficult to train a zero case without polluting the classification of the other cases because they have overlapping attributes.